# Randomly selecting enum values according to few rules

Tags: c++, random, enums, switch-statement

Please have a look at the following code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    enum Movement{STAND,WALK,RUN,CRAWL};

    Movement state = (Movement)(1+rand()%4);

    for(int i=0;i<100;i++)
    {

    cout << state << endl;

    switch(state)
    {
        case STAND: 
            cout << "You can walk or crawl" << endl;        
            while(state==WALK || state==CRAWL){
            state = (Movement)(1+rand()%4);}
            break;


        case WALK: 
            cout << "You can stand or run" << endl;
            while(state==STAND || state==RUN){
            state = (Movement)(1+rand()%4);}
            break;


        case RUN: 
            cout << "You can walk" << endl;
            while(state==WALK){
            state = (Movement)(1+rand()%4);}
            break;

        default: 
            cout << "You can stand" << endl;
            while(state==STAND){
            state = (Movement)(1+rand()%4);}

    }

    }
}
```

In here, there are few rules. Lets call them as legal transitions

1. From stand, he can walk or crawl
2. From Walk, he can stand or run
3. From Run, he can walk
4. From Crawl, he can stand

So, here, if the legal transitions should be randomly selected. But, however, it should be according to the rules provided above. For an example, if "STAND" is selected, next thing to be selected should be "WALK" or "CRAWL" likewise. But as you can see here, all the result

```
2
You can walk
```

Why is that? Please help!

UPDATE:

Following code is with do..while loop, as suggested in a reply

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    enum Movement{STAND,WALK,RUN,CRAWL};

    Movement state = (Movement)(1+rand()%4);

    for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
    {

    cout << state;

    if(state==STAND)
    {
        cout << " STAND is selected" << endl;

    }
    else if(state==WALK)
    {
        cout << " WALK is selected" << endl;

    }
    else if(state==RUN)
    {
        cout << " RUN is selected" << endl;
    }
    else if(state==CRAWL)
    {
        cout << " CRAWL is selected" << endl;
    }

    switch(state)
    {
        case STAND: 
            //cout << "You can walk or crawl" << endl;        
            do{state = (Movement)(rand()%4);}
            while(state==WALK || state==CRAWL);

            break;


        case WALK: 
            //cout << "You can stand or run" << endl;
            do{state = (Movement)(rand()%4);}
            while(state==STAND || state==RUN);
            break;


        case RUN: 
            //cout << "You can walk" << endl;
            do{state = (Movement)(rand()%4);}
            while(state==WALK);
            break;

        default: 
            //cout << "You can stand" << endl;
            do{state = (Movement)(rand()%4);}
            while(state==STAND);

    }

    }
}
```

It is still the same. Now I get different answers, but not correct ones!!

Comment: 2 is state RUN, enums start at value of 0 unless you set it explicitly to another value. So from RUN you get "You can walk"

Comment: You should do as Andrew has suggested below. Use the debugger to understand your code. Look at what the `state` becomes when you are exiting your `do..while` loops. There are some logic errors there. If you just look at your conditions and think about what they are saying you will see the problem. Look, for instance, at the one in the `STAND` case - from `STAND` you can move to the state of either `WALK` or `CRAWL`, now look at your condition. If the condition is `true` the loop repeats.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your logic is in the wrong order; your `while` loops will all be skipped because the `state` is still what it was when you entered the particular `case`. You might rewrite them with `do-while` to ensure they run at least once.

Comment: +1 good catch! Also, OP is not seeding rand() with a call to srand() before using it.

Comment: OK, I edited an update. Now I get different answers, but they are wrong!!

Comment: First, you should look at srand() as @pstrjds said. You get the same sequence by design; otherwise no one could debug programs with random numbers in them. Next, your `cout` statement comes _after_ the `do-while` loop has been executed, so it isn't "wrong" but it's what makes you _leave_ the loop. I suggest you use a debugger to go one line at a time through your program to understand the flow better.

Answer (score 1):

In C and C++ enums start at 0 by default.

Comment: but why I am always getting the same result?